# Manhwa where a girl lost her family to a woman demon and she becomes part of the holy knights to look for her sister

Tags: story-identification, manga

A girl lost her family to a woman demon and she becomes part of the holy knights to look for her sister and rises to the second strongest?

Then the knights get a mission to look for a saint from a selection of children. However there is a devil child too and it's hard to tell the difference as demons are attracted to both the saint and the devil so they have the protect the children until they are sure of it.

The girl protects a white-haired boy in an abandoned mansion with only one female old butler. (The butler was kinda creepy too.) And then she is tricked by a demon that looks like her sister and "betrays" the boy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour and what colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: full color, pink hair I think and she had a staff

Comment: What language did you read this in? Did you read it as a comic (i.e. Webtoon) or a novel? "Hey, Little Duke, Just Trust This Sister!" is a decent match, but the English translations don't cover a lot of details. She reaches rank 2, lost her family to a fire (no mention of a demon, but it's the kind of thing that gets brought up again later on). She dies and has pink hair after returning to the past. No demons or saints yet, but it could happen.

Comment: I read it in English, its a manhwa or a webcomic. It had quite a few chapters and it isn't a recent manhwa. Its a reincarnation manhwa where she returns to the past after being killed by the older version of the devil but she doesn't remember who it was. It's not "Hey, Little duke, just trust this sister!", thank you for helping though!

Comment: Can you put a specific year to that? If you don't know the publication year, do you remember when you read it? That would help eliminate any newer series, so it makes searching a lot easier.

Comment: I dont remember the publication year but I read it about 7-9 months ago.

Comment: Do you remember how far back in time she goes after being killed? Or how old she was before and after? Is she a knight before or after (or both) going back in time? Is this also an isekai story where she reincarnates in a game/book world, and then goes back in time? If she's the second strongest, do you remember anything about the first strongest?

Comment: I dont remember when she died, I don't think there were many memories of her past. But she reincarnates from when she was young, 4-6 years? To the time when her sister was still alive, then died to a spider-like demon.I don't remember if it was an isekai story and if she reincarnated into a book. The strongest was a similar kid with black hair and red eyes his name started with K. He had a similar situation to her where her twin brother had "died" but later it said his twin brother was a part of him using magic cuz he didn't want him to die. The girl and guy didn't get along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *[The Golden Light of Dawn](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-golden-light-of-dawn)*. It is licensed by [Manta](https://manta.net/series/1751).

> **After losing her family in a demon attack**, Rosha is reborn as the 777th most powerful magic knight in the Golden Dawn Society. To avenge her family, she trains hard and rises through the ranks against the odds. Then, **she is tasked with protecting little Joshua, who is said to be the Child of God**...

There are a number of differences from the question, but the general outline is the same. She loses her family to a demonic attack in the first chapter, to "Ramia", a half-serpent, half-woman demon (not spider).

[image: Snake demon killing her family]

She escapes with her sister Lily (they're not twins, Rosha is explicitly older, but their birthdays are only off by 1 day) and tells her to run off and stays behind. God grants Rosha power as she's about to die, and kills the Ramia. She's picked up by a man, is told that there's no trace of her sister, and swears she'll find her sister and kill any other demons she can find.

There's no second life involved; she dies and is immediately resurrected by God's power. After a timeskip she becomes ranked 77th instead of 777th - it's possible she reaches #2 later on, but at least at first she's not there. The guy she doesn't like is, at least at this point, ranked third.

The prologue shows the possible child of god, with hints that he may actually be a demonic child instead.

[image: Child of god with demonic aura]